# Property of Diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, problem-solving, diffeomorphism

Let us consider

- $X=[-1,1]$
- $Y= \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x=0, 0\leq y \leq 1/2 \} \cup \{  (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | y=0 , 0\leq x \leq 1/2 \}$

I hope they are not diffeomorphic as Y have a sharp corner. I don't know how to say this precisely.

Kindly help me with this

Comment: They could be diffeomorphic, since they are homeomorphic. First you have you say what smooth structures are given on X, Y.

Comment: As Subsets of R and R^2  respectively

Comment: The second is not a  differentiable submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.